# Android random IOExceptions with CipherInputStream and ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, android, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm using a CipherOutputStream wrapped by ObjectOutputStream to write data (and of course the corresponding input streams to read it) structures to disk in my Android app. Reading is successful in almost 100% of the time, but sometimes reading fails (no writing errors at all) with a wide viarity of exceptions:

- java.io.StreamCorruptedException
- android.util.Base64DataException: bad base-64
- java.io.EOFException
- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NULL is not a constant in Currency
- java.io.IOException: Error while finalizing cipher
- ...

I tried to replace CipherOuputStream with SealedObject but the exceptions stayed the same. I also synchronized the access to the file with a ReadWriteLock.

This is one of the classes being serialized. Every file holds only one ArrayList of object of one class (so only one call to writeObject()).

```
public class SdTransaction implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID =-784295048753453223L;
    private int mAmount;
    private SdCurrency mCurrency;
    private Date mCreatedAt;
    private Source mSource;
    @Nullable
    private String mAccountId;
    private boolean mIsVirtual;

}
```

My code locks basically like this (no error handling, no synchronisation):

```
OutputStream os = mContext.openFileOutput("test.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
os = new Base64OutputStream(os, Base64.NO_PADDING);
os = new CipherOutputStream(os, mCipher);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

oos.writeObject(mSerializable);
oos.flush();
oos.close();


InputStream is = mContext.openFileInput("test.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
is = new Base64InputStream(is, Base64.NO_PADDING);
is = new CipherInputStream(is, mCipher);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

Object o = ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Here are some stack traces:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader (ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init> (ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at com.xyz.model.pin.SdPinRepositoryPersister.load (SdPinRepositoryPersister.java:72)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder$Initializer.init (SdComponentHolder.java:293)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:109)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:120)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdSmooveExecutorService.onDataSetChanged0 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:106)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdSmooveExecutorService.access$000 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:35)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdSmooveExecutorService$1.run (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: d2
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.corruptStream (ObjectInputStream.java:675)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:788)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues (ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject (ObjectInputStream.java:454)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject (ArrayList.java:661)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at com.xyz.model.persistance.SdDiskPersister.load (SdDiskPersister.java:80)
    at com.xyz.model.persistance.SdPersisterComposite.load (SdPersisterComposite.java:67)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder$Initializer.init (SdComponentHolder.java:390)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:109)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:120)
    at com.xyz.model.data.SdDataService.onDataSetChanged0 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:106)
    at com.xyz.model.data.SdDataService.access$000 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:35)
    at com.xyz.model.data.SdDataService$1.run (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad byte at 2
    at java.nio.charset.ModifiedUtf8.decode (ModifiedUtf8.java:60)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF (DataInputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF (DataInputStream.java:173)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF (DataInputStream.java:169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor (ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc (ObjectInputStream.java:1634)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc (ObjectInputStream.java:657)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc (ObjectInputStream.java:1663)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc (ObjectInputStream.java:657)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject (ArrayList.java:661)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues (ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject (ObjectInputStream.java:454)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues (ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject (ObjectInputStream.java:454)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject (ArrayList.java:661)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues (ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject (ObjectInputStream.java:454)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject (ArrayList.java:661)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass (ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy (ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent (ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject (ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at com.xyz.model.persistance.SdDiskPersister.load (SdDiskPersister.java:80)
    at com.xyz.model.persistance.SdPersisterComposite.load (SdPersisterComposite.java:67)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder$Initializer.init (SdComponentHolder.java:385)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:109)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:120)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdService.onDataSetChanged0 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:106)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdService.access$000 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:35)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdService$1.run (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

android.util.Base64DataException: bad base-64
    at android.util.Base64InputStream.refill (Base64InputStream.java:148)
    at android.util.Base64InputStream.read (Base64InputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.InputStream.read (InputStream.java:162)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.fillBuffer (CipherInputStream.java:99)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read (CipherInputStream.java:155)
    at com.xyz.model.streams.sync.SdSupervisedInputStream.read (SdSupervisedInputStream.java:80)
    at libcore.io.Streams.readFully (Streams.java:81)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort (DataInputStream.java:152)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader (ObjectInputStream.java:2061)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init> (ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at com.xyz.model.persistance.SdDiskPersister.load (SdDiskPersister.java:77)
    at com.xyz.model.persistance.SdPersisterComposite.load (SdPersisterComposite.java:67)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder$Initializer.init (SdComponentHolder.java:389)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:109)
    at com.xyz.dagger.SdComponentHolder.init (SdComponentHolder.java:120)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdService.onDataSetChanged0 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:106)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdService.access$000 (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:35)
    at com.xyz.model.smoove.execution.SdService$1.run (SdSmooveExecutorService.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Has anyone experienced something similar or can give me some tips how to localize the error? Only devices with API 21 and higher seem to get those errors...

Comment: Please provide the exact error messages in each case. Why the base64-encoding?

Comment: I added some stacktraces :) The base64 encoding has no deeper meaning, I'll remove it soon. But I don't think that the Base64 stream can create those issues

Comment: Nor do I, but it's still redundant. Now can you post the class being serialized? And tell us whether it has any of `readObject()`, `readResolve()`, `writeObject()`, or `writeReplace()` methods? And if so show them?

Comment: I added a class being serialized above. I use this serialization with different classes, but they are all about the same, just different attributes. I serialize always a list of those objects, so I have only one call to writeObject() before the stream is closed

Comment: Do *any* of these objects have any of the methods I mentioned? Or is any of them `Externalizable`? I can't see any other explanation. And I'd still like to see a stack trace for `StreamCorruptedException`. NB The `IllegalArgumentException` you posted has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: Nope, they only have some basic getter and setters. SdCurrency is a enum, so this should be fine too. And they are not Externalizable. I'll add a stack trace in some minutes :)

Comment: I added the StreamCorruptedException.

Comment: Well it is looking like an Android storage problem in that case. You could run this program for twenty years on a hard-disk file system and not expect a failure.

Comment: Thats what I belived too. But I wrote a AndroidTestCase today which created 10.000 random objects, wrote them to disk, read them, verified the integrity of every single one of them and deleted the file. The test ran 10.000 times without an single error on a device which produces this errors from time to time when using the app. Could a concurrency issue damage the files?

Comment: Of course it could damage the files. Using a file lock isn't much use as it doesn't prevent anything except other *processes* from claiming file locks. You should protect both these chunks of code with the `synchronized` keyword, taking care to synchronize on something that will always be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution but I still have no clue about the issue. When replacing ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream with a BufferedReader/BufferedWrite and a JSON serialization for the objects everything works fine. Something seems to be going on with the ObjectInputStream when used in the Service...